# Jenkins user using docker (inside docker container)

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have a dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins:1.651.1
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
USER root
RUN groupadd docker
RUN usermod -a -G docker jenkins
USER jenkins
```

I add my user `jenkins` to the group `docker`.
When I access my container:

```
jenkins@bc145b8cfc1d:/$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
jenkins@bc145b8cfc1d:/$ whoami
jenkins
```

This is the content of my `/etc/group`on my container

```
jenkins:x:1000:
docker:x:1001:jenkins
```

my jenkins user is in the docker group

```
jenkins@bc145b8cfc1d:/$ groups jenkins
jenkins : jenkins docker
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to use docker-commands with my jenkins user. I'm on Amazon EC2 Container Service.

This is how I start a container from my image:

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v
/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro -v
/lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02
-v /lib64/libudev.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
-p 8080:8080 --name jenkins -u jenkins --privileged=true -t -i
my-jenkins:1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This was my 'solution' but it only worked on Ubuntu (not on my centos).
Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins:1.651.1
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates \
  && echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list \
  && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D \
  && apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y docker-engine
RUN gpasswd -a jenkins docker
USER jenkins
```

Run command:

```
docker run -d -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock test-jenkins
```

On Ubuntu:

```
jenkins@c73c683b02d7:/$ whoami
jenkins
jenkins@c73c683b02d7:/$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
c73c683b02d7        test-jenkins        "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   

                         condescending_wing
```

It has something to do with `gid` I think:
cat `/etc/group` in container (on ubuntu and centos).

```
jenkins:x:1000:
docker:x:999:jenkins
```

cat `/etc/group` on Ubuntu (also 999)

```
docker:x:999:ubuntu
```

cat `/etc/group` on Centos (different gid)

```
docker:x:983:centos
```

There is probably a solution for this. But I only needed Ubuntu so did not go further in this.

Comment: Pretty sure you nailed it, gid docker needs to be the same on the host and in the container for /var/run/docker.sock to be accessible by docker users inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Once your container is running, you can "patch" into the running container using different users using

```
docker exec -ti -u 0 jenkins bash // root
docker exec -ti -u 1 jenkins bash // probably jenkins
```

Using the root user, you can `su jenkins` if you need to switch to the jenkins user from the root user.

If you want to run docker containers inside your existing container (it seems like that is what you're trying), remember to start your docker container with the `--privileged` flag, eg `docker run --privileged ...`

Comment: I'm using the --privileged to start. when I use -u root I'm able to perform docker commands because I'm root user in my container. But I want to edit my dockerfile so I'm able to perform those commands with my jenkins user.

Comment: Have you done `sudo gpasswd -a jenkins docker` followed by restarting the docker service `sudo service docker restart` ?

Comment: Yes tried the first command. I can't restart the docker service from inside a dockerfile.

Comment: `docker exec -ti -u 0 jenkins bash`, now I'm inside the container as the root user; run `/etc/init.d/docker start`, now `docker ps` will no longer give you that error message `Is the docker daemon running on this host?`. Then switch back to jenkins using `su jenkins`

Comment: yes it's running on the host. But I want to be jenkins user inside my container. Not root. So I try to add my jenkins user in the docker group but is does not seem to work.

Comment: It needs to run inside the container as well if you want to make use of it inside the container.

Comment: I'm mounting the sockets to my container. (when I'm root user in my container I'm able to use docker, but not as jenkins user)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111448/discussion-between-jan-vladimir-mostert-and-maxc).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MaxC, did you find a solution? I'm also curious

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. Although it maybe isn't.